# Android Firebase: как удалить объект, найдя его по значению поля?

Tags: java, android, запрос, firebase, firebase-database

Firebase database нод "memories/" содержит объекты типа Memory{String name; int cost; ...} Мне нужно получить объекты конкретного "name" поля (например  "party") и удалить их или изменить "cost" поле.
Пробовал так...

```
memoryRef.orderByChild("party").equalTo(true).setValue(null);
```

Прочитал это
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Но там только про обработку событий. Помогите, у меня есть такое чувство, что это должно быть просто...

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский язык,  пожалуйста

Comment: Попробуйте `memoryRef.equalTo("party", "name")`.